# SoapUI (Groovy) - passing a node value from a response to another request if a condition is true

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

I would appreciate any help with following:

XML Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns3:GetSeatPlanAvailabilityResponse xmlns:ns2="http://stagecoach.com/schemas/engine/common" xmlns:ns3="http://stagecoach.com/schemas/engine/seat">
         <ns3:header>
            <ns2:version>1.0</ns2:version>
         </ns3:header>
         <ns3:journeyDetails>
            <ns2:journeyId>4769046</ns2:journeyId>
            <ns2:origin>
               <ns2:cityId>120</ns2:cityId>
               <ns2:description>Memphis, TN</ns2:description>
               <ns2:stop>MEM</ns2:stop>
            </ns2:origin>
            <ns2:destination>
               <ns2:cityId>320</ns2:cityId>
               <ns2:description>Austin, TX</ns2:description>
               <ns2:stop>AUS</ns2:stop>
            </ns2:destination>
            <ns2:departureDate>2014-07-28Z</ns2:departureDate>
            <ns2:departureTime>04:00:00Z</ns2:departureTime>
         </ns3:journeyDetails>
         <ns3:noOfNonReservableSeatsRemaining>70</ns3:noOfNonReservableSeatsRemaining>
         <ns3:singleSeats>
            <ns2:singleSeat>
               <ns2:seatPlanKey>US1</ns2:seatPlanKey>
               <ns2:seatId>7ecc7775-6caa-4e17-80d7-6cfa46be507b</ns2:seatId>
               <ns2:seatNumber>1</ns2:seatNumber>
               <ns2:seatClassCode>FRN</ns2:seatClassCode>
               <ns2:seatDeck>UPPER</ns2:seatDeck>
               <ns2:availableForSelection>true</ns2:availableForSelection>
            </ns2:singleSeat>
            <ns2:singleSeat>
               <ns2:seatPlanKey>US2</ns2:seatPlanKey>
               <ns2:seatId>fe73cc9a-7c4f-4d1f-80e5-6131926af694</ns2:seatId>
               <ns2:seatNumber>2</ns2:seatNumber>
               <ns2:seatClassCode>FRN</ns2:seatClassCode>
               <ns2:seatDeck>UPPER</ns2:seatDeck>
               <ns2:availableForSelection>true</ns2:availableForSelection>
            </ns2:singleSeat>
            <ns2:singleSeat>

               <ns2:seatPlanKey>US3</ns2:seatPlanKey>
               <ns2:seatId>20121517-d657-438f-bc26-92bb98b20bb5</ns2:seatId>
               <ns2:seatNumber>3</ns2:seatNumber>
               <ns2:seatClassCode>FRN</ns2:seatClassCode>
               <ns2:seatDeck>UPPER</ns2:seatDeck>
               <ns2:availableForSelection>true</ns2:availableForSelection>
            </ns2:singleSeat>
            <ns2:singleSeat>
               <ns2:seatPlanKey>US4</ns2:seatPlanKey>
               <ns2:seatId>b93be6b7-ebb9-482e-9ec2-3c9d32beab32</ns2:seatId>
               <ns2:seatNumber>4</ns2:seatNumber>
               <ns2:seatClassCode>FRN</ns2:seatClassCode>
               <ns2:seatDeck>UPPER</ns2:seatDeck>
               <ns2:availableForSelection>true</ns2:availableForSelection>
  </ns2:singleSeat>
         </ns3:singleSeats>
         <ns3:doubleSeats/>
         <ns3:salesClassInformation>
            <ns2:seatClassCode>FRN</ns2:seatClassCode>
            <ns2:salesClassCode>SFRN</ns2:salesClassCode>
            <ns2:salesClassDescription/>
            <ns2:price>3.00</ns2:price>
            <ns2:maxPassengers>1</ns2:maxPassengers>
         </ns3:salesClassInformation>
         <ns3:salesClassInformation>
            <ns2:seatClassCode>LEG</ns2:seatClassCode>
            <ns2:salesClassCode>SLEG</ns2:salesClassCode>
            <ns2:salesClassDescription/>
            <ns2:price>7.00</ns2:price>
            <ns2:maxPassengers>1</ns2:maxPassengers>
         </ns3:salesClassInformation>
         <ns3:salesClassInformation>
            <ns2:seatClassCode>TBL</ns2:seatClassCode>
            <ns2:salesClassCode>STBL</ns2:salesClassCode>
            <ns2:salesClassDescription/>
            <ns2:price>9.00</ns2:price>
            <ns2:maxPassengers>1</ns2:maxPassengers>
         </ns3:salesClassInformation>
      </ns3:GetSeatPlanAvailabilityResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

---

XML Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bas="http://stagecoach.com/schemas/engine/basket" xmlns:com="http://stagecoach.com/schemas/engine/common">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bas:AddSeatToBasketRequest>
         <bas:header>
            <com:version>1.0</com:version>
            <com:retailOperation>US</com:retailOperation>
            <com:channel>WEB</com:channel>

         </bas:header>
         <bas:basketItemId>56227</bas:basketItemId>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <bas:seatSelectionInput>
            <com:passengerOrdinal>1</com:passengerOrdinal>
            <com:SeatId>7ecc7775-6caa-4e17-80d7-6cfa46be507b</com:SeatId>
         </bas:seatSelectionInput>
         <bas:seatSelectionInput>
            <com:passengerOrdinal>2</com:passengerOrdinal>
            <com:SeatId>d653b812-3230-4a31-88e7-a4ad867fb131</com:SeatId>
         </bas:seatSelectionInput>
      </bas:AddSeatToBasketRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My requirement is such that I need to pass `<ns2:seatId>` to another request, first it should look for condition when `<ns2:availableForSelection>` is `TRUE`, or else it should skip to 'FALSE' and select `and pass it to request

Could some one please provide groovy script for above logic?

Comment: I edited your post, however, both the Request and Response above are incomplete XML. Also: 1) Do you only need this done in Groovy? Why? And 2) What do you expect when `seatId` is `false`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my post to include complete XML's. 1) I prefered Groovy because I am using Soap UI but I am also open to any other workable code alternative to Groovy. 2) My requirement is to look for 'True' first and pass seatID and Skip to 'False' when true are left and pass SeatID to <com:SeatId> request. Thanks

Comment: Your requirement is still unclear! The Response has multiple `availableForSelection=true`; which one do you want? Your Request has multiple `SeatId`; which one do you want? I do not understand "Skip to 'False' when true are left"; it does not make sense.

Comment: My request will have multiple SeatID's depending on the number of passengers, my requirement is only for 1 passenger i.e request will have only 1 seatID. My requirement is pass seatID from response when availableForSelection=true to seatID within request. if availableForSelection=true = false, just ignore and end. so i will manually go back and pass a different journeyID. Hope this is clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust the below code for your exact needs, as there is still information missing in your question.

```
// to read a node from your Response
def grUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
// depending on when / how your are doing this, you will need to provide the exact test step name
def xmlHolder = grUtils.getXmlHolder("${context.currentStep.name}#Response")

def seatIdNode = xmlHolder.getDomNode("//*:singleSeat[availableForSelection='true']/seatId")

// if nothing was found
if(seatIdNode == null) {
    testRunner.cancel("seatId was not found!")
    return
}

// you can store this in a testcase property
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("seatId", seatId.firstChild.nodeValue)
// and use it in your next Request as '${#TestCase#seatId}'
```

There is a way to write the `seatId` directly into the next Request. If you wish to go that route, I have a [blog entry](http://siking.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/dynamically-create-elements-in-a-soapui-request/) that describes how to generate XML requests.

Lastly, all of this could also be done with pure SoapUI test steps, without the use of Groovy. A Conditional GoTo step would check if the XPath above exists, and bypass your next Request if it is not. A Transfer Property step using the same XPath as above would transfer the value of `seatId` to your next Request.

Comment: Thanks  for your response. I have edited above script "def xmlHolder = grUtils.getXmlHolder("GetSeatPlanAvailability#ResponseAsXml")" and when I run it and it returns the following error xml exception:Unexpected element:CDATA error at line:4. TransferProperty worked though.

Comment: Try just `def xmlHolder = grUtils.getXmlHolder("GetSeatPlanAvailability#Response")`.

Comment: did that now it returns a different error. "NullPointerException:cannot get property 'firstchild' on null object error at line 5

Comment: Try this. You are going to have to adjust the XPaths for your case, as I do not have access to your app, so I cannot debug it.